# How to prevent OLEDB create new excel file when path in connection string not exist

Tags: c#

Example:

```
public static DataTable dTable;

    public bool openDBSheet(string sheet)
    {
        String str= 
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            + @"Data Source=D:\Item1.xlsx;"
            +"Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes'";

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(str);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "$]", conn);
            dTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dTable);
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The real file name is "Item.xlsx" but when I change the path to "D:\Item1.xlsx;" (that not exist) the program create a new empty file named "Item1.xlsx".
Can anyone please explain me why and how to solve it?

Or maybe there's another better way to validate not exist excel file using OLEDB ???

Comment: Use `File.Exists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`File.Exists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (!File.Exists(@"D:\Item1.xlsx"))
  return;
```